# Reduce-Side Join ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception using Java

Tags: java, exception, mapreduce

trying to run a Reduce Side join on 3 datasets. Unfortunalyy, i keep getting an ArrayIndex exception. I have tried to handle it with a try & Catch, but to no avail. Can someone please recommend a solution?

```
package Joins;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class JoinReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> 
{
Map<String, String> divStkJoin = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> divStkMetaJoin = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> stockData = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> metaData = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> divData = new HashMap<String, String>();
Text k = new Text();
Text v = new Text();

public void setup(Context context)
{   
    metaData.clear();
    divData.clear();
    stockData.clear();
    divStkJoin.clear();
    divStkMetaJoin.clear();
}

public void reduce(Text keys, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
{

    Iterator it = values.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){
    String [] keyLine = keys.toString().split(","); 
    String valueLine = values.toString();

    try {

        if(keyLine[4].equals("_s"))
        {
            String keyLineStock = keyLine[0] + "," + keyLine[1] +"," + keyLine[2] + "," +   keyLine[3];
            stockData.put(keyLineStock, valueLine);

        }
        else if(keyLine[4].equals("_d"))
        {
            String keyLineDiv = keyLine[0] + "," + keyLine[1] +"," + keyLine[2] + "," + keyLine[3];
             divData.put(keyLineDiv, valueLine);
        }

        else if (keyLine[1].equals("_m"))
        {
            String keyLineMeta = keyLine[0];
            metaData.put(keyLineMeta, valueLine);
        }
        else
            return;

    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){return;}
    }   



        //JOINS

        for(Entry<String, String> entryStock: stockData.entrySet())
            for(Entry<String, String> entryDiv: divData.entrySet())
                {
                    if(entryStock.getKey().equals(entryDiv.getKey()))
                    {
                        divStkJoin.put(entryStock.getKey(), entryStock.getValue()+ ","+ entryDiv.getValue());
                    }
                }
        for(Entry<String, String> entrydivStkJoin: divStkJoin.entrySet())
        {
            String [] entrydivStkJoinKeyArr = entrydivStkJoin.getKey().toString().split(",");
            for(Entry<String, String> meta: metaData.entrySet())    
            {
                String [] metaArr = meta.getKey().split(",");

                if(metaArr[0].equals(entrydivStkJoinKeyArr[1]))
                {
                    divStkMetaJoin.put(entrydivStkJoin.toString(), meta.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
    }   



public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{

        String keyJ;
        String valJ;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : divStkMetaJoin.entrySet())
    {
        keyJ=entry.getKey();
        valJ=entry.getValue();
        Text k = new Text(keyJ);
        Text v = new Text(valJ);

        context.write(k, v);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: which is the statement that produces the index out of bounds?

Comment: It is in the reduce method.

Comment: Do you guarantee to allways pass 5 keys?

Comment: Looks like `keyLine` doesn't always have 5 elements. You can print it and debug it yourself.

Comment: BobTheBuilder & xgeorgekx, I am well aware of that. I thought i took care of it using the If statements. Most of them take 5 arguments, and the others use 2.

Comment: You need to check for `keyLine` length before accessing an index if you suspect it may have fewer elements.

Comment: Thanks BobTheBuilder. So perhaps something like "keyLine.length==5 && keyLine[4].equals("_s")". 

I'd run it it first, but it is a Mapreduce job in one node and takes 40 minutes, so i have to make sure.

Comment: Also, is it now safe to take out the try && catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error comes from this line:

`if(keyLine[4].equals("_s"))`,

My solucion would be ckecking if keyLine is **null** or if keyLine < 4:

```
 if(ss == null || ss.length()<4){
     return;
 }
```